# Alamofire Error kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire` to connect to a `web service`. It seems as if the `server` has an **invalid certificate**. I would like to have alamofire `ignore` this `invalid cert`. I added the following values to my `info.plist`:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>example.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>TemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
                <key>ExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>IncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>ExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But I am still getting this issue. What else should I do to allow this `invalid cert?`

**UPDATE:** Still having same issue.